# simple relationship question

Tags: ee2

I have one channel for workshops and one for events. each workshop can have multiple events but each event can only belong to one workshop. workshops are rarely added/edited. but new events are added frequently.

so my set-up is as follows:

```
workshops
    title                           Text Input
    description                     Text Area

events
    title                           Text Input
    date-and-time                   Date
    belongs-to-workshop             Relationship (to workshops, single)
```

now I have a template where I want to show all workshops and under each workshop I want to list related events. 
one easy way (so far) seems to be another field in the workshops channel: some field like "related events" (a mulitple-relationship pointing to events channel). but that means the admin would have to edit the workshop entry each time they add a new event. I'd like to make it easy on the user and just let them add events and link the event to a workshop by using the "belongs-to-workshop" drop down.

question: how could I access the events in my 'workshops' template which looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="workshops"}
<div class="workshop">
    {title}, {description}
    Related Events: {???}
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

does the "workshop" entry not know which events are related? I suppose that's what the old "reverse related entries" tag was for?

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See documentation here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#accessing-parents)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="workshops"}
  {parents field="relationship_field"}
    {parents:title} - {parents:field1} - {parents:field2}
  {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: that doesn't work because workshops is the parent and there is no relationship field in "workshops" - it is in the "events" channel. I'm still hoping to somehow load events into workshop template without needing a relationship field in workshops.

Comment: Uhm. this does work... I guess I got confused by addressing "events" as {parents} when I'm thinking of one workshop being able to have multiple events (children) but each event can only have one workshop (parent?).